# No concurrent connections with nginx-clojure using Java

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I build nginx-1.13.1 with nginx-clojure-0.4.5 for Ubuntu 16.04.

I used the sample java code from nginx-clojure site (see below) but inserted a 1 second sleep before responding. I then launched 10 curl http calls to invoke my java code. I expected that after 10 secs all 10 curl http calls would return more or less simultaneously. But instead then returned one at a time at 1 second interval. This implies that nginx and/or nginx-clojure is not processing them concurrently, but serially. Is it supposed to do this? Here's the console output:

```
ubuntu:/share/java$ ./launchControllers.sh 10
Fri 28 Jul 15:27:21 BST 2017
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/1 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/2 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/3 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/4 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/5 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/6 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/7 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/8 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/9 &
curl http://localhost:80/myJava/10 &
Fri 28 Jul 15:27:21 BST 2017
ubuntu:/share/java$ 
2017-07-28 15:27:23: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:24: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:25: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:26: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:27: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:28: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:29: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:30: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:31: Hello, Java & NGINX!
2017-07-28 15:27:32: Hello, Java & NGINX!
```

Here is my nginx-clojure java invoke method:

```
public Object[] invoke( Map<String, Object> request ) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 1000 );
    }
    catch ( Throwable t ) {
        t.printStackTrace( System.err );
    }

    return new Object[] {
            NGX_HTTP_OK,    //http status 200
            ArrayMap.create( CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain" ),    //headers map
            new SimpleDateFormat( TS_FORMAT ).format( new Date() ) + ": " +
            "Hello, Java & NGINX!\n"    //response body can be string, File or Array/Collection of them
    };
}
```

I also tried substituting the sleep for a upd socket that waits for a udp packet and spawning 100 curl http calls (each udp socket listening to unique port number). The resultant behaviour was very strange. Even if I sent a packet to each udp port, the http call hangs and I have to kill the curl calls individually. Why does nginx/nginx-closure behave like this?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood how nginx works. [This explains it](https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/). No wonder the above behaviour. However, I'd still like to know how, using nginx-closure and with multiple curl calls as above, I can listen out for a UDP packet on a port that is uniquely mapped to each curl call.

Answer (score 0):

Try nginx-clojure thread pool mode , e.g.

```
jvm_workers 40;
```

Or use more than one Nginx worker processes, e.g.

```
worker_processes 8;
```

More notes can be found from https://nginx-clojure.github.io/more.html#311-more-about-nginx-worker-process